# Unable to run test in Chrome with Specflow

Tags: bdd, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I am trying to run my specflow test in Chrome Browser. Every time I runs, following error comes:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'ChromeDriver'. ---> unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision: 3b3c00f2d95c45cca18ab944acced413fb759311
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (See inner exception for details.)
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision: 3b3c00f2d95c45cca18ab944acced413fb759311
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
>   TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

However when I ran the same script for IE, it runs fine. Only with Chrome driver it gives an error. Also every dependency (all *.dlls), chromedriver.exe  are part of the solution. I am running my test in VS 2013.

Does anyone have the idea what could be the crux of this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning. It appears there may have been an update to Chrome making the driver non-compatible. I downloaded and replaced the Chrome driver with the latest one [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Answer (score 2):

When firsttime i try ChromeDriver i also get that error message. The problems because when **using nuget to install ChromeDrvier**. i choose **wrong one.** When you search ChromeDriver there may be 4 or 5 items has same name. `**Select "Chromium.ChromeDrier" version 2.21.0 is work for me**`

**Update**: I'm not use Specflow. I use visual studio - selenium. But i think this error will same